# projection - frustum to a NDC cube mapping

Tags: projection, projection-matrices

[This particular resource about projection matrices](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/projection-matrices-what-you-need-to-know-first) tells us

> that while projection, the points within the view frustum are mapped to the range [-1,1](later converted to [0,1]). But, also the z coordinates are mapped to [0,1], hence the view frustum is converted to a unit view volume.

But, when we project the z coordinates onto a plane at `z'` , shouldn't all the `z` coordinates be `z'`, therefore resulting in a plane? What am I not understanding in this projection mechanism?